# JavaScript - Alert Message in iPad Application

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, alert

Apologies for the rudimentary question, however the problem is I can't seem to find what one would think is a simple yes or no.

I have a backbone application that gets loaded into a webIUView (I believe is the proper terminology) within an iPad application.

I am simply attempting to do an alert within the application, testing on desktop (safari/chrome/etc) works as expected.  However once I fire up the iPad application, my alerts aren't happening.

Investigation tells me phonegap has a notifier (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html) however I really don't want to use another framework just for an alert message.

I guess my first question is how come a simple alert doesn't work in iOS?  Secondly, if it doesn't should I just do a simple dialog box that would mimic it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Code sample

I noticed this when implemented a network connection handler

```
    window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
        onNetworkChange(false);
    });
    window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
        onNetworkChange(true);
    });

    function onNetworkChange(_isConnected){
        var msg;
        (_isConnected == false) ? msg = "Networking Connection Lost" : msg = "Network Connection Established";

        window.alert (msg);

    }
```

Because I wasn't sure if there was a problem with my code, in another view I decided to do a simple

```
    window.alert ('test');
```

And nothing, I must be either going crazy or overlooking something.

Comment: alert works perfectly on any os, give us some sample of your code

Comment: I just added a code snippet, this code is in router.js

Comment: try inserting an alert out of functions, just to see

Comment: I did, I actually stuck the alert in render which I am 100% certain gets called.  I thought maybe because the listener was in router that perhaps for some odd reason I couldn't alert from there (wouldn't make sense why I wouldn't) so I tried a few things.  Super super strange.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe iOS Safari fires `online` and `offline` events. You can read more about iPad connection status event issues here:

http://ednortonengineeringsociety.blogspot.com/2010/10/detecting-offline-status-in-html-5.html

Comment: It's certainly possible, I assumed that if desktop Safari (windows) supports it, then its mobile version would (however I guess that may not be the best assumption).

Comment: I appreciate the link thank you, I actually didn't come across that yet although appears to be an similar approach.

Comment: If is certainly possible why this event are not fired?

Comment: The plot thickens, so it turns out online and offline events do get fired within an iOS app (same as mobile safari right?).  I know this because instead of trying to do an alert I simply do a window.location = 'http://espn.com'; and toggle my WIFI sure enough my application redirects to espn.  Why the alert isn't happening is still a mystery.

Comment: Wow that is interesting. Anything being output to the debugger console?

Comment: Yup, not sure why I didn't think of doing a simple output within the function to show me the event is being registered on the device.  My educated guess at this point is that it's something to do with the scope of alert.  I'm using a combination of backbone and require (it's a modular implementation), I have a feeling the view that is calling the alert function may be throwing an error on the device.  Either that or you simply cannot do alert from JavaScript within an iPad application (I have yet to find documentation that states this).

Comment: I actually went as far as implementing a basic jquery ui dialog box instead.